# Using SqlCommand to save datarow changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have the following test application to push changes to a field that will be added and deleted condensing the numbers but I am unable to get the changes to actually save to the SQL table

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RMGIAX90; Initial Catalog=CredUAT; Integrated Security=True;");
            int cnt = 0;

            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM ScanlineZonestopleft Order By ZoneOrder", connString);

            da.Fill(ds, "ScanlineZonestopleft");
            dt = ds.Tables["ScanlineZonestopleft"];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dr["ZoneOrder"] = cnt;
                cnt ++;
                dr.AcceptChanges();
                //MessageBox.Show(dr["ZoneOrder"].ToString());
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Update Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add an update command to your dataadapter

Comment: When I tried this I was unable to plug the variable in. It seemed to update and push the same number to every record. I am sure my update was wrong somehow as I was updating the entire table instead of each record one at a time as it went through the for each

Comment: So what did your update look like?

Comment: "UPDATE ScanlineZonestopleft SET ZoneOrder = " + cnt

As it went through each time it numbered them all up sequentially instead of one at a time.

Comment: You need a where clause to pass the key of the record that is being updated.

Comment: It will need to do all records but one at a time. I am not certain as to how to pass a WHERE for that as it would need to do each one once then not pull it again.

This is why I was trying to do it by datarows ad I could say for each entry. I am not sure how to do that in a WHERE SQL statement.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx  for example.

Comment: No luck. I am getting an error with the SQL or an update to the entire table stile in my various attempts.